# Generating a SHA-256 hash from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, shell, sha256

I know the string "foobar" generates the SHA-256 hash `c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c8974e592c2fa383d4a3960714caef0c4f2` using
http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator

However the command line shell:

```
hendry@x201 ~$ echo foobar | sha256sum
aec070645fe53ee3b3763059376134f058cc337247c978add178b6ccdfb0019f  -
```

Generates a different hash. What am I missing?

Comment: `sha256sum < foobar`. No need for [cat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/cat.html), [echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/echo.html), [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/printf.html), ... See also [Useless use of cat?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/873282)

Comment: @koppor `< foobar` is not the same as `echo foobar |`. The equivalent for `echo foobar |` would be `sha256sum <<< foobar` but that does add a newline to foobar just like `echo`.

Comment: Does not work, it claims `foobar: No such file or directory`.

Comment: `sha256sum < foobar` isn't nearly the same thing as `echo foobar | sha256sum`. The former has the file "foobar" provide standard input to the `sha256sum` process, with its contents. The latter has the `echo` built-in provide input to the `sha256sum`, the input being the string "foobar" that is passed as a command line argument to `echo`.

Answer (score 557, accepted):

`echo` will normally output a newline, which is suppressed with `-n`. Try this:

```
echo -n foobar | sha256sum
```

Comment: Is this command `sha256sum` same as digest command in Solaris ??

Comment: seems so, http://www.opensolarisforum.org/man/man1/digest.html, `digest -a sha256` should do it.

Comment: NOTE: on OS X (BSD), it's `echo -n foobar | shasum -a 256`

Comment: On OSX, it might be handy to create an alias: `alias sha256sum='shasum --algorithm 256'`

Comment: Why does it end with *-

Comment: @PhilipRego It's the shasum of input on stdin, therefore instead of the filename `-` is printed.

Comment: On Windows use set with echo to omit the new line `echo|set /p="foobar" | .\openssl.exe dgst -sha256`

Comment: to show only the hash and not a - or *- add the following to command shown   | cut -d " " -f1

Comment: Output `-` is terrible... I know the file name already I piped into you silly! You couldn't do just one thing?!

Answer (score 132):

If you have installed `openssl`, you can use:

```
echo -n "foobar" | openssl dgst -sha256
```

For other algorithms you can replace `-sha256` with:

- `-blake2b512`
- `-blake2s256`
- `-md4`
- `-md5`
- `-md5-sha1`
- `-ripemd`
- `-ripemd160`
- `-rmd160`
- `-sha1`
- `-sha224`
- `-sha256`
- `-sha3-224`
- `-sha3-256`
- `-sha3-384`
- `-sha3-512`
- `-sha384`
- `-sha512`
- `-sha512-224`
- `-sha512-256`
- `-shake128`
- `-shake256`
- `-sm3`
- `-ssl3-md5`
- `-ssl3-sha1`
- `-whirlpool`

The list of all algorithms can be found from here:

```
openssl dgst -list
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the number of rounds you want in sha512? I looked and could not find it and wondered if you would know?

Comment: @AlistairMacDonald - I don't know exactly what you are looking for. AFAIK, SHA512 needs 80 rounds; If you want to manipulate the function, it won't be sha512 anymore. BTW, you can search / ask your question in [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ "Cryptography Stack Exchange").

Answer (score 55):

If the command sha256sum is not available (on [Mac OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) for example), you can use:

`echo -n "foobar" | shasum -a 256`

Comment: Nice! I've added this to my .bash_profile
function sha256() { echo -n "$*" | shasum -a 256 }
and call like: ~$ sha256 foobar

Comment: Or do you mean *[Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29)*? (no 's', *Maverick*). It was released in 2010 whereas Mac OS X v10.9  was released one month before this answer.

Answer (score 37):

`echo -n` works and is unlikely to ever disappear due to massive historical usage, however per recent versions of [the POSIX standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/echo.html), new conforming applications are "encouraged to use [`printf`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/printf.html)".

Answer (score 17):

For the **sha256** hash in ***base64***, use:

```sh
echo -n foo | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64
```

#### Example

```sh
echo -n foo | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64
C+7Hteo/D9vJXQ3UfzxbwnXaijM=
```

Comment: I'm glad I scrolled down - had been trying to get a base64 hash by combining `shasum` and `base64` and kept getting the wrong result. The key is the `-binary` arg passed to `openssl`, thanks for posting!

Comment: make sure you filter the output before pipng it into another type. In linux we get stdin= and some give a - at the end. always cut that out using  | cut -d " " -f2  . Depending on where you want to cut you may need -f1

Comment: I have been fiddling with this for hours, thanks for the openssl trick! +1 !

Answer (score 14):

Use `printf` instead of `echo` to avoid adding an extra newline.

```
printf foobar | sha256sum
```

For an arbitrary string, the `%s` format specifier should be used.

```
printf '%s' 'somestring' | sha256sum
```

Comment: and do not confuse print and printf, print still add a new line

Comment: That should be `printf '%s' "foobar" | sha256sum` if you don't absolutely know the value of "foobar", since printf takes a format-string.  And `print` is only an echo-alike in zsh, as far as I know, where it takes `-n`.

Comment: @PhilP Good point. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 13):

`echo` produces a trailing newline character which is hashed too. Try:

```
/bin/echo -n foobar | sha256sum
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe that `echo` outputs a trailing newline. Try using `-n` as a parameter to echo to skip the newline.