# Linux command line SHA-256 hash different from online tools?

Tags: java, linux, security, spring-security, hash

I was looking for a quick way to compute the SHA-256 hash of a password so I could upload some test data into a database that we are using Spring Security to authenticate against.

First I found the linux utility `sha256sum` and ran it again the password "admin" and got this result:

```
fc8252c8dc55839967c58b9ad755a59b61b67c13227ddae4bd3f78a38bf394f7
```

Then I tried an couple online services (for fun):

http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator
http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=admin

and both gave me this very different result:

```
8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
```

Why are they different and which is correct?

Comment: Are you sure the first hash is a 256 bit one? It only has 160 bits. The second one seems reasonable with its 256 bits.

Comment: @Manuel -- Yes, I got it mixed up...fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a sha256 from the Linux command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358420/generating-a-sha256-from-the-linux-command-line)

Comment: @HDave Check your results here https://sha256generator.online/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into this problem while doing something similar.

What I was doing was something like `echo string | sha256sum`, I think.

I'd get a different result when I ran this through the php hash generator. The reason was because of the new line that echo added.

I don't know if you're using echo but if you are try `echo -n string | sha256sum`.

Comment: In the immortal words of Homer Simpson --- DOH!

Comment: Saved me from pulling out my hairs ! Thanks :)

Comment: a typo correction "sha256num" -> "sha256sum"

Answer (score 5):

According to `echo -n "admin" | shasum -a 256` on my Mac OS X, the later is correct. Note that you need to do `echo -n`, otherwise there's a `\n` in the string that is hashed as well. Since `shasum` is a Perl script, you might have it as well. If so, try to use that.