# SHA-256 test vectors

Tags: linux, testing, sha256

I'm attempting to replicate the values found here http://www.nsrl.nist.gov/testdata/

SHA-256 should hash "abc" out to

```
 BA7816BF 8F01CFEA 414140DE 5DAE2223 B00361A3 96177A9C B410FF61 F20015AD
```

but under linux with sha256 sum I am getting this.

```
edeaaff3f1774ad2888673770c6d64097e391bc362d7d6fb34982ddf0efd18cb

adam@adam-desktop:~/code/android-casual/trunk/CASUALcore$ echo "abc">./test.tmp
adam@adam-desktop:~/code/android-casual/trunk/CASUALcore$ sha256sum test.tmp
edeaaff3f1774ad2888673770c6d64097e391bc362d7d6fb34982ddf0efd18cb  test.tmp
adam@adam-desktop:~/code/android-casual/trunk/CASUALcore$ echo "abc"|sha256sum
edeaaff3f1774ad2888673770c6d64097e391bc362d7d6fb34982ddf0efd18cb  -
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a sha256 from the Linux command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358420/generating-a-sha256-from-the-linux-command-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `echo` appends a newline to the string.  Use `echo -n` instead:

```
$ echo "abc" | shasum -a 256
edeaaff3f1774ad2888673770c6d64097e391bc362d7d6fb34982ddf0efd18cb  -
$ echo -n "abc" | shasum -a 256
ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad  -
```