# Sha256 with pipe

Tags: shell, sha256, bitcoin

Step 5-6 of manual:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses

Calculating sha256sum secondly:

> 5 - Perform SHA-256 hash on the extended RIPEMD-160 result
>   445C7A8007A93D8733188288BB320A8FE2DEBD2AE1B47F0F50BC10BAE845C094
>
> 6 - Perform SHA-256 hash on the result of the previous SHA-256 hash
>   D61967F63C7DD183914A4AE452C9F6AD5D462CE3D277798075B107615C1A8A30

I try to repeat step 6, but sha256sum is wrong:

```
# echo -n 445C7A8007A93D8733188288BB320A8FE2DEBD2AE1B47F0F50BC10BAE845C094 | sha256sum
7760845dcfd8c366ae89620be2f368d255d710bc7493628ca0dcded9ca476e5a  -
# echo -n 445C7A8007A93D8733188288BB320A8FE2DEBD2AE1B47F0F50BC10BAE845C094 | openssl sha256 
(stdin)= 7760845dcfd8c366ae89620be2f368d255d710bc7493628ca0dcded9ca476e5
```

even this wrong too:

```
# echo 445C7A8007A93D8733188288BB320A8FE2DEBD2AE1B47F0F50BC10BAE845C094 | openssl sha256 
(stdin)= 9edec8be4a03dd9e605f465c60ae4c77c752516f58384016c6c7384028b39f6e
```

I have read this:
[Generating a sha256 from the Linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358420/generating-a-sha256-from-the-linux-command-line)

How to get: D61967F63C7DD183914A4AE452C9F6AD5D462CE3D277798075B107615C1A8A30?

Is wiki wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hash the raw byte data rather than its ASCII hex dump.

```
$ echo -n $'\x44\x5C\x7A\x80\x07\xA9\x3D\x87\x33\x18\x82\x88\xBB\x32\x0A\x8F\xE2\xDE\xBD\x2A\xE1\xB4\x7F\x0F\x50\xBC\x10\xBA\xE8\x45\xC0\x94' | sha256sum
d61967f63c7dd183914a4ae452c9f6ad5d462ce3d277798075b107615c1a8a30  -
$ echo -n $'\x44\x5C\x7A\x80\x07\xA9\x3D\x87\x33\x18\x82\x88\xBB\x32\x0A\x8F\xE2\xDE\xBD\x2A\xE1\xB4\x7F\x0F\x50\xBC\x10\xBA\xE8\x45\xC0\x94' | openssl sha256
(stdin)= d61967f63c7dd183914a4ae452c9f6ad5d462ce3d277798075b107615c1a8a30
```

Comment: How to convert ascii to raw bytes? xdd, hexdump?

Comment: echo -n 445C7A8007A93D8733188288BB320A8FE2DEBD2AE1B47F0F50BC10BAE845C094 | xxd -r -p | sha256sum